# Updated doc not attaching as PDF in Gmail

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail, google-docs

I'm using Google Apps Script to create a copy of a doc file and save data from spreadsheet to the new file, then send it to email as a PDF attachment. Everything is working as it should except the pdf file is showing the default values which was from the source file instead of updated values.

Here are my codes,

```
var lr = dataSheet.getLastRow();
var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange(lr, 1, 1, 3).getValues();

var firstName = dataRange[0][1];
var lastName = dataRange[0][2];
var email = dataRange[0][3];

var emailText = "Hi "+firstName+",\n\nThank you for signing up.";
var emailSubject = "Test PDF";

var fileTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById("FILE_ID");  // Get Template File Id
var fileCopied = fileTemplate.makeCopy("Doc Copy-"+new Date()).getId();  // Make a copy of the template and get the id of the new file.

var doc = DocumentApp.openById(fileCopied);  // Get destination doc
var dbody = doc.getBody();  // get destination doc's body

// Replace the fields with values from sheet.

dbody.replaceText("First Name", firstName);
dbody.replaceText("Last Name", lastName);
dbody.replaceText("EmailAddress", email);

Utilities.sleep(1000);

// Send Email with PDF attachment
MailApp.sendEmail(email, emailSubject, emailText, {
    attachments: [doc.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
});
```

How can I get the updated doc in the mail as a PDF attachment?

Answer (score 0):

I think, it can be done if we consider the 'files' as 'blobs', that is how Google treats the Google Docs files. Please see this example which converts and sends Google Spreadsheets as PDF files.

```
/* Send Spreadsheet in an email as PDF, automatically */
function emailSpreadsheetAsPDF() {

  // Send the PDF of the spreadsheet to this email address
  var email = "amit@labnol.org"; 

  // Subject of email message
  // The date time string can be formatted in your timezone using Utilities.formatDate method
  var subject = "PDF Reports - " + (new Date()).toString(); 

  // Get the currently active spreadsheet URL (link)
  // Or use SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("<<SPREADSHEET URL>>");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Email Body can  be HTML too with your logo image - see ctrlq.org/html-mail
  var body = "PDF generated using code at ctrlq.org from sheet " + ss.getName(); 

  var url = ss.getUrl();
  url = url.replace(/edit$/,'');

  /* Specify PDF export parameters
  // From: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579
    exportFormat = pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    gridlines = true / false
    printtitle = true (1) / false (0)
    size = legal / letter/ A4
    fzr (repeat frozen rows) = true / false
    portrait = true (1) / false (0)
    fitw (fit to page width) = true (1) / false (0)
    add gid if to export a particular sheet - 0, 1, 2,..
  */

  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   // export as pdf
                + '&size=letter'                       // paper size
                + '&portrait=false'                    // orientation, false for landscape
                + '&fitw=true&source=labnol'           // fit to width, false for actual size
                + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
                + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
                + '&fzr=false'                         // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
                + '&gid=';                             // the sheet's Id

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets(); 

  //make an empty array to hold your fetched blobs  
  var blobs = [];

  for (var i=0; i<sheets.length; i++) {

    // Convert individual worksheets to PDF
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheets[i].getSheetId(), {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
      }
    });

    //convert the response to a blob and store in our array
    blobs[i] = response.getBlob().setName(sheets[i].getName() + '.pdf');

  }

  //create new blob that is a zip file containing our blob array
  var zipBlob = Utilities.zip(blobs).setName(ss.getName() + '.zip'); 

  //optional: save the file to the root folder of Google Drive
  DriveApp.createFile(zipBlob);

  // Define the scope
  Logger.log("Storage Space used: " + DriveApp.getStorageUsed());

  // If allowed to send emails, send the email with the PDF attachment
  if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) 
     GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {attachments:[zipBlob]});

}
```

More in here: [Convert and Email Google Spreadsheets as PDF Files](http://ctrlq.org/code/19869-email-google-spreadsheets-pdf)